# Search entire Linux server for a specific text gets Freeze/Timeout

Tags: linux

I need to scan a Linux server for a forbidden word, so it won't appear in any file in that server.
I used
`grep -rnw '/' -e. ForbiddenWord`
but after few minutes it freezes and even if I keep it overnight - nothing in the morning.

Any idea for doing this request? Maybe other command?
Maybe i need to ignore some folders? file types?

Thanks :)

Comment: This does not seem to be the command, you are using. `grep -e. ForbiddenWord` does not search for the word `ForbiddenWord`. Instead `-e.` searches for any character in the file with the name `ForbiddenWord`.

Comment: Thanks...sorry. not so familiar. so should i do this ? fgrep -c -e ForbiddenWord '/'

Comment: Bear in mind that after you run that command, that forbidden word will be inside some log file ;)

Answer (score 1):

Search only regular files, hide errors, and print the matching file names:

```
find / -type f -exec grep -H "$str" \{} \+ 2> /dev/null
```

@ceving is correct.  Seems about 3 times as fast with '+' vs ';'

Comment: Use '+' instead of ';' to terminate the `-exec` option. This makes the search much faster.

Comment: Well...got an exception after few hours of timeout error.....